# how to update texture in starling movieclip on runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, starling-framework

I am working on a prototype in which i have used starling framework. I have used starling movieclip in which we have to provide texture as constructor parameter.

```
var demoMc:MovieClip = new MovieClip(textures:Texture, fps:Number = 12);
```

but i have to give that texture parameter at runtime because i have to change the texture runtime, is there any way so that we can provide it runtime texture.

Comment: Did you found answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to update your texture in starling movieClip on runtime, then we can use addframe() method of starling movieClip or we can dynamically load that texture and feed it in movieClip.

If we go through the methods of movieClip, we will found the answer.